# Julia's garbage collection of ccall allocated data

Tags: julia

I was hoping someone could clarify one aspect of the behaviour of the Julia garbage collector and how it interacts with memory allocated by a call to a C function using `ccall`.

For example, I am making the following call:

```
    setup::Ptr{Void} = ccall(("vDSP_DCT_CreateSetup", libacc), Ptr{Void},
                         (Ptr{Void}, UInt64, UInt64),
                         previous, length, dct_type)
```

This function allocates memory and initializes memory for a `DFT_Setup` object (the details of this are irrelevant). The library also provides a destructor to be called on the `DFT_Setup` to deallocate memory once the object is no longer needed.

Is calling the destructor necessary in Julia? i.e. Does the garbage collector handle freeing `DFT_Setup` when it is appropriate, or should I make a call to the C deallocator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the Julia GC can only clean up the memory allocated by Julia itself, it has no knowledge of memory allocated by `ccall`s.

The usual way to solve this is to call the destructor from the [finalizer](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/base/#Base.finalizer), defined when in the constructor, e.g. see [RCall.jl](https://github.com/JuliaStats/RCall.jl/blob/d2102e6ed7bdbce741393fca1ccf896510ed8180/src/types.jl#L266).

Comment: Thank you! I figured this would be the case, but I thought it would be wise to check.